# Mocha test reporting Object.hasOwn is not a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am using mocha and sinon to test and I am using node 16.19.0

I am using Object.hasOwn in my code and the test is currently failing with:

"Object.hasOwn is not a function"

I'm not really sure why is doesn't exist in the first place.

I have tried to stub it

```
Sinon.stub(Object, 'hasOwn').returns({});
```

but I get the error:

Cannot stub non-existent property hasOwn

If I monkey patch it the issue goes away.

```
Object.hasOwn = Sinon.stub().returns({});
```

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Can you confirm the `Object.hasOwn()` API exists?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you're inside a TS context here but if you are, outdated TS definitions can cause the same issue.

You need both node and TS to recognise `Object.hasOwn`. I've just fixed a similar issue resulting from my IDE pointing at an old TS.